# iPhone App - turning json array to email attachement

Tags: ios, json, csv, email-attachments

I am making an iPhone app that runs queries on a db and displays the results to the user, Ideally I would like to have the option to email those results once they are displayed

I am working with a json array. From what I read online, I believe I would have to convert it to a CSV file first and then attach it in an email. The user should then be able to download the file form his or her email and open it on excel.

How would I go about this task? Would I need to make an API for the conversion or is this something I can do on xcode? I am still new at this and would appreciate any details about the process.

Comment: Do the results need to be an attachment or can they be in the body of the email?

Comment: In an attachment to be opened in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can convert a Json to Csv in Xcode itself
- If your json (NSDictionary) keys are identical throughout your array, its easy to do it like below.

  ```
   NSArray *keys = [self.dictionary allKeys];

   // -- you need to sort the keys first because the index order is not identical every time in nsdictionary.

   NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

   NSMutableString *large_CSV_String = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:0];
   for(int i = 1; i<[sortedKeys count]; i++){

   [large_CSV_String appendFormat:@",%@",[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i]];

   }

   [large_CSV_String appendFormat:@"\n"];
  ```
- Assume that the below jsonArray comprises of nsdictionary objects with exactly the above keys

  ```
  // -- your array object NSArray *jsonArray 


  for (NSDictionary *ajsonObject in jsonArray){

   [large_CSV_String appendFormat:@"%@",[ajsonObject objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:0]]];

   for(int i = 1; i<[sortedKeys count]; i++){

   [large_CSV_String appendFormat:@",%@",[ajsonObject objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i]]];

   }
   [large_CSV_String appendFormat:@"\n"];

  }
  ```

  // -- Finally you'll get a string of CSV

  // -- You may NSLog the value and see

  // -- Save this string as csv and attach in email.

  // -- I don't have the exact code which I wrote last time, I'm writing this post with a little memory left. Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation raja, it was really helpful. I was able to create my csv string and print it out with the NSLog. I just had a follow up question. What exactly does it mean to "save the file as csv and attach in email"? I am going off of this tutorial to make my email attachment (http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-create-email-attachment/). So I cannot use that string as the attachment and set its MIME type? There is an additional step to be done? Again thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry it was mistake 'Save this file as csv', actually its 'Save this string as csv file and attach in email'

Comment: You can write a string as file using 'writeToFile:' method in NSString.

Comment: Got it. I really appreciate the help!